# Aerospike namespace configuration options

Tags: aerospike

I've recently been getting involved in implementing an Aerospike data store into our product. We've been trying to work out the best configuration for our namespace. The requirement to persist data means we need to have a storage-engine as a device. we have specified data-in-memory as true.

My question is: does `data-in-memory` attempt to load **ALL** the backing store data into memory as the vague description implies?

> Keep a copy of all data in memory always.

Or will it pay attention to the `memory-size` setting on the namespace and only load `memory-size` amount of data from the backing store?

Description of the setting was retrieved from [documentation](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/).

I have been talking to the guy who first implemented aerospike to try and find out if he knew and wasn't sure so I'm looking for clarification.

For reference my namespace config looks something like this, with an obviously smaller memory quota than backing store

```
namespace Test {
    replication-factor 2
    memory-size 4G
    default-ttl 0
    storage-engine device {
        file /opt/aerospike/data/Test.dat
        filesize 16G
        data-in-memory true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will keep all the data in memory. Aerospike does not yet have a partial cache implementation to keep the most used data in the provided memory.

Comment: as you say "not yet" does that mean having an intelligent memory utilisation of the system is in the workings? as we can have TBs of storage in our system running with data-in-memory is going to be useless to us and Aerospike is going to have to run entirely off Disk.

Comment: Not in the short/medium term. Cannot publicly comment on timelines.

Answer (score 2):

Your data will only exist in memory, while the disk is used for persistence for recovery in the event of server restart. The reason the [`filesize`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#filesize) is larger than the [`memory-size`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#memory-size) is that disk space is needed for maintenance operations such as defragmentation of blocks. Disk devices are block devices, and in the default 1MB [`write-block-size`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#max-write-cache) you can fit multiple records so operations such as defrag occur by moving records from blocks that are less than [`defrag-lwm-pct`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#defrag-lwm-pct) full. This takes extra blocks, so you need that spare capacity.